# Ruby: Ignore first input in a loop with this expression, help understand this expression

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration

I needed a loop to read text line-by-line but completely ignore the first line. I come across this very handy expression posted online by Nobuyoshi Nakada. This expression skips one iteration of Enumerator. Can someone help to explain the last step in evaluation? Here is the example for illustration. This code will print 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 5. I am new to programming, I don't know if this a common solution. It took me 3 days to find it!

```
(0..5).each do |i|
  if (first=true)..false and first
    next
  end
  puts i
end
```

I attemplted to evaluate `if (first=true)..false and first` with `pry` but could not get deep enough.

1. `(first=true)` evaluates to: **true** (value of `first` is **true**)
2. `(first=true)..false` evaluates to: **true**..false (value of `first` is still **true**)
3. `(first=true)..false and first` evaluates to: **true**..false and **true**, which is **true** and **true** (value of `first` is still **true**)
4. `if (first=true)..false and first` evaluates to: if(**true**), executes **next** statement and exits *if* loop (value of `first` is now **nil**)
5. Next iteration of Enumerator returns to `if (first=true)..false and first` expression (value of first is still **nil**)
6. This step evaluates to **false**: `if(first = true)..false and nil` (value of `first` on the left side is **true** and on right side is **nil**(**false**)
   and I am lost here…

QUESTION: Why is `first` on the right side of if expression is not assigned "**true**". It seems that value of `first` is **true** and **nil** at the same time? Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The flip-flop operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-Flip-Flop) is a somewhat obscure feature of Ruby inherited from Perl (like most of Ruby's more obscure features). It is an expression that flips and flops back and forth between `true` and `false`.

Basically, it starts out as `false`, then it "flips" to `true` as soon as the *left* expression evaluates to a *truthy* object, and it "flops" back to `false` again as soon as the *right* expression evaluates to a *truthy* object.

So, the condition starts out as `false`. The *first time* through the loop, the *left* expression evaluates to a *truthy* value (in Ruby, assignments evaluate to the value that is being assigned) and as a side-effect also assigns `true` to `first`. Since the *left* expression evaluates to a *truthy* value, the flip-flop flips to `true`, and the entire condition now is `true and true` which is `true`. So, we execute the body of the conditional expression, which is simply `next`, i.e. skips the current iteration.

The *second* (and all the other times) through the loop, the flip-flop has *already* flipped to `true`, so now we *only* check the *right* expression for when the flip-flop should flop back to `false` again. The *left* expression is no longer checked. Well, the right expression is just `false` so we will never flop back to `false` again, the flip-flop will now always be `true`. However, the left expression will not be evaluated (we only check the right expression for when to flop back again), which means the assignment to `first` will never be executed, which means `first` is an un-initialized local variable, which means it evaluates to `nil`, which is *falsy*, which means that `true and nil` evaluates to `false`. And this will continue to be so for every iteration of the loop.

So, this code uses an obscure feature (the flip-flop) in an even more obscure manner (not as a conditional but simply to "disable" execution of the assignment). This is very definitely *not* code that any Rubyist would write. A much more idiomatic way would be

```
(0..5).drop(1).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

or

```
(0..5).each.with_index do |n, idx|
  next if idx.zero?
  puts n
end
```

Note that nobu is a Ruby core developer, Japanese, and one of the earliest adopters of Ruby. The Japanese early adopters of Ruby are a pretty different sub-community from the larger Ruby community. It may very well be that this is actually a well-known and well-understood idiom among Japanese Rubyists and/or Ruby core developers. The thing about idioms is that if you know what they look like and you know what they mean, you don't need to understand them, so code like this *may* be okay, *if* it is idiomatic. But it certainly is *not* idiomatic in the larger Ruby community.

Comment: Ooh, I totally went for explaining the flip-flop and completely forgot the whole "how do I drop the first line" question :D +1

Comment: thank you, and @Amadan for your thorough explanations. I learned something very interesting today. I find this flip-flop a very useful operator, and after I mostly figured it out I can use it in many situations. As for alternative ways I am amazed how simple the first option is (should it be drop(0) to print from 1 to 5, by the way?). Second option I actually considered, but I thought it was not Ruby enough...

Comment: It probably isn't idiomatic (or not any more), as it throws a warning about assigning in a conditional. An upgraded version with `first = !first` instead of `first = true` works without warning.

Comment: @Amadan Oh, yes! It actually does throw a warning, forgot about that. Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 2):

Several key insights:

- `left..right` in an `if` is a flip-flop operator, as noted by Jörg W Mittag: it evaluates the left side (and *only* left side) as long as it is falsy (returning that value), then evaluates the right side (and *only* right side) as long as it's truthy (returning `true`), then goes back to evaluating the left side. This allows you to write things like `if (row == 5)..(row == 10)` and get the rows from 5th to 10th (because it returns `false` for left side from 1 to 4, then `true` from left side from `5`, then flips and evaluates the right side from 6 to 10, returning `true` each time, and flipping the last time at 10; then back to returning `false` for the rest of the rows from the left side).
- since `first` is not mentioned outside the block, it is a variable scoped to the block; that means its value does not carry over between steps, and is reset to `nil` in each iteration

So:

- In the first step, `(first = true)` is `true`; the flip-flop returns `true` and flips to the right side
- `true and first` evaluates to `true`; `next` is processed, loop loops.
- In the second step, the local variable `first` is back to `nil`
- the flip-flop is evaluating the right side -- `false` -- it doesn't flip, and returns `true`.
- `true and first` is `false`; `next` is *not* evaluated
- The third and further steps are all identical to the second, since nothing changes: the flip-flop will be evaluating the right side, `first` will continue to be `nil`.

EDIT: an important typo :P

Comment: I like this idea of selecting rows based on this flip-flop, I can actually use it to return rows based on how recent the record is, i.e between 5 and 7 days ago without having to refer to dates, which are not important! I will be sorry to see the flipflop go - I like it  - and I just learned about it!

Comment: It's actually a bad example as it can be rewritten to `if row >= 5 && row <= 10`; but for example `if (line =~ /BEGIN/) .. (line =~ /END/)` has a much less trivial rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

You're right that `(first=true)..false` evaluates to `true..false`, but that's not a valid statement - it will raise `ArgumentError: bad value for range`.

Maybe someone else understands how this solution is working but I think it's definitely not the clearest or easiest way to get it done.

If your goal is to get input N times and ignore the N inputs, you can do something like this:

```
num_times_to_ignore = 1
num_times_to_process = 3

# ignore some lines
num_times_to_ignore.times { gets.chomp }

# process each input individually
num_times_to_process.times.each { do_something_with(gets.chomp) }

# or you can get all the inputs before processing
results = num_times_to_process.times.map { gets.chomp }
results.each { |input| do_something_with(input) }
```

Comment: This is not a `Range` literal, it is the flip-flop operator.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the flip-flop operator (which I understand has its roots in Perl), it is explained quite well in [this posting](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/). It's little-used and many  Rubiests would like to see it go the way of the [dodo bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodo) (but it has supporters).

Comment: it is getting late, and I need to think over your example a bit more, it does not make sense to me yet...

Comment: When it comes down to it you can just gets.chomp and not assign it to a variable when you want ignore a line of input. It's great that you understand the flip flop operator but you question was if there is a 'better way to ignore the first line of input. Given that I have hardly ever seen the flip flop operator used and the syntax is identical to range, I wouldn't recommend it.